# No Transaction ID in Payment Invoice

Tags: magento, payment-gateway, invoices

I've developed a Payment Method extension for Magento. In this extension, I've added:

```
protected $_canRefund = true;
```

However, when I click an invoice and select Credit Memo, I can only see 'Refund Offline' and not 'Refund'. All tutorials I followed insist that I only have to change that value to true to activate the button (obviously I still have to implement the refund method and the actual refund procedure) but I can't see a way to do this.

If I, within a block on the order screen, execute this line `$order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->canRefund();` it does indeed return true, but still no luck with the actual credit memo.

**Edit**

I've changed the title of the question to reflect my new find.
Basically, the reason it's not appearing is because my invoices aren't created with transaction IDs - I have no idea why, but this is my capture payment method that runs when generating an invoice:

```
public function capturePayment($order) {
    try {
        if (!$order->canInvoice()) {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Cannot create an invoice.'));
        }
        $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice();
        if (!$invoice->getTotalQty()) {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Cannot create an invoice without products.'));
        }
        $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);
        $invoice->register();
        $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
               ->addObject($invoice)
               ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
        $transactionSave->save();
        $order->setState('processing', 'payment_received', "Payment has been received", false);
        $order->save();
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        Mage::throwException("Error Taking Payment, Please Try Again:\n" . $e);
    }
}
```

Why isn't a transaction ID being assigned to my capture?

Comment: please put the original `capture()` from your module (in model) where you will be getting success of the payment capture from gateway. You will be getting a reference id(transaction id) there for the captured payment

Comment: I've been successful in my attempts and it now works. I'll post the solution, shortly

Comment: *bump* did you say you found a solution @DanHanly?

Comment: @DougMcLean I'd love to help you out, but this was over a year ago, and I've no idea what the solution is. Apologies.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem here :(

Answer (score 0):

check below url

http://www.spinonesolutions.com/2009/10/magento-enable-paygate-refunds/
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7846/capture-void-refund-not-showed-in-magento-admin-area

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-payment-method-api-based

hope this help you

Comment: I've discovered why, but I still can't solve it. Please check the latest edits to the question.